# How to implement `int array` with `NSMutableArray` with less code writing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'am trying to learn the best practices of using NSMutableArray implementing int arrays. At first glance it appears that much more code need to be written to manage them relative to other languages like C or JAVA.

I appeal to user experience for two reasons: (i) find out about code writing practices for ios-style int arrays; (ii) find about reasoning why despite the heavy coding these arrays justify themselves vs `int array[7]` in daily practice;

Below is a set of exemplified templates of how one can initialize, allocate, read and write a NSMutableArray implementing integer one-dimensional array in a very generic manner.

```
int arrayIndex;
int arrayValue;

//DECLARE arrayOfInt
@property (atomic, strong)  NSMutableArray *arrayOfInt;

//ALLOCATE AND INITIALIZE arrayOfInt
self.arrayOfInt = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//...fill arrayOfInt (write)  
[self.arrayOfInt addObject: [NSNumber  numberWithInt: arrayValue]];

//... read arrayOfInt
arrayValue = [(NSNumber*)[self.arrayOfInt objectAtIndex: arrayIndex ] intValue];

//...replace arrayOfInt (write)
[self.arrayOfInt replaceObjectAtIndex: arrayIndex withObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arrayValue ]];
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Is there a simple way to manage ios-style integer arrays (without restriction) than I presented in the question?

Comment: you do not make sense, can you review your question and look if you can ask it in better way?

Comment: What is `self.butOnStars`?

Comment: Modern Objective-C syntax can be a bit more compact (and will help keep your types consistent).  You can do things like `@(<numerical expression>)` to get an `NSNumber` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:<numerical expression that we hope is int type>]`.

Comment: Please work on naming conventions.  See [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Code Naming Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH)

Comment: Aaron Golden, can you please write a line of the code per your suggestion replacing any line in my code?

Comment: NoBodyNada, thanks that was a typo

Comment: You know, you can use C arrays in Objective-C.  You don't have to use NSArray.  (But try to find NSArray functionality in C and you have a problem.)

Comment: I've noticed a few of you downvoted my question, for whatever reason unknown to me anyway. I still think that my question is of certain community value and for many the MOTIVATION for using ios-style integer vs c-style is not clear. By downvoting such generic question you force me to take it off the forum. Do you believe this is the right thing to do? Then think before voting...

Comment: There is a tendency, due to laziness in some cases, ignorance in others, and occasionally fear, to ignore the possibility of using ordinary C structures in an Objective-C program.  There are cases where, eg, using a C array makes sense, for it's simplicity, "light weight", and in some cases actual functionality.  But doing so requires some extra thought and care, particularly when object pointers are involved.

Comment: As to the code required to use NS(Mutable)Array, yes, it gets kind of verbose and clumsy, but the power of the concept makes up for that, and very often there are more concise ways of doing it once you learn the ropes.

Comment: I am the AUTHOR of the original post. I REFORMULATED it towards being a service for the members with similar concerns. The ANSWERS are of additional value towards the same subject. I wish this post and accompanied material would survive [HOLD] and remain available.

I agree that in initial formulation the question was ambiguous, that is not the case now to my best believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also write the same in shorter way ( if it is what you were asking .... ) like this:

//... DECLARE ARRAY

```
property ( atomic, strong ) NSMutableArray *ARRAY;
```

//...ALLOCATE AND INITIALIZE ARRAY

```
_ARRAY = [NSMutableArray new];
```

//...fill ARRAY (write)

```
[_ARRAY addObject:@( VALUE )];
```

// ... declare array with values

```
_ARRAY = @[ @( INT1 ), @( INT2 ), @( INT3 ) ];
```

//... read

```
int VALUE = [[_ARRAY objectAtIndex:INDEX] intValue];
```

//...replace (write)

```
[_butOnStars replaceObjectAtIndex:INDEX withObject:@( VALUE )];
```

Comment: `self.ARRAY` should be used instead of `_ARRAY` because of memory-management benefits.

Comment: I'm a bit oldschool and memory management is smth. what I want to have under my control ( still do not use ARC ), but ofcourse self. notation can be also used.

Comment: `self.ARRAY` is safer because it calls the accessor methods.  Also, you can access the array with the modern syntax: `int VALUE = [array[INDEX] intValue];`

Comment: `@[ @( INT1 ), @( INT2 ), @( INT3 ) ]` doesn't return a NSMutableArray it needs a call to `mutableCopy`

Comment: Mysiaq, I agree especially 
>_ARRAY = @[ @( INT1 ), @( INT2 ), @( INT3 ) ]; 
would de facto cause saving on code size. matrix3003

Answer (score 2):

If you want int array [7] in Objective-C, you write

```
int array [7];
```

Objective-C is an extension of C. Every C code is legal Objective-C code. There's also Objective-C++ which is an extension of C++, so you can use std::array  in Objective-C if you feel like it.

On the other hand, if you want an array with adjustable size, in C you'll have to use malloc, realloc, keep track of the size, keep track of the lifetime, call free at the right time, worry about dangling pointers, which is an awful lot easier to handle in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Would have agreed once I started with objC, but it got a lot better with the modern syntax

Let's compare both:

```
@property (atomic, strong)  NSMutableArray *ARRAY;
//c array
@property (atomic, strong)  int *ARRAY;
```

Looks the same.

ALLOCATE AND INITIALIZE ARRAY

```
self.ARRAY = [NSMutableArray array];
self.ARRAY = [@[@1, @2, @3, @4] mutableCopy];
//c array
self.ARRAY = malloc(numElements*sizeof(int));
```

Definitly prefer NSMutableArray

DEALLOCATE ARRAY

```
self.ARRAY = nil; //not really needed
//c array
free(self.ARRAY);self.array=nil;
```

Definitly prefer NSMutableArray

...fill ARRAY (write)

```
[self.ARRAY addObject: @(VALUE)];
self.ARRAY[ARRAY.count] = @(VALUE);
//c array
Not existent
```

Definitly prefer NSMutableArray

... read

```
VALUE = [self.ARRAY[INDEX] intValue];
//c array
VALUE = self.ARRAY[INDEX];
```

C array gets the point here

...replace (write)

```
self.ARRAY[INDEX] = @(VALUE);
//c array
self.ARRAY[INDEX] = VALUE;
```

Almost the same

To sum up:
You get easier memorymanagement, fast enumeration, some bonus methods and almost the same code while using a NSMutableArray. The tradeoff is you have this NSNumber creation and the objC messaging. So if it was about speed, I definitly still would choose the c array. But for most cases the NSArray is good enough. And don't have to debug badAccess errors but get proper indexOutOfBounds errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

The array types for iOS are "heavy" because they do a lot and they are objects that must be initialized.

If you chose to do so you could use c-styled arrays but then you would not have the benefits of using the array types.